# GWT PlaceHistoryGenerator ignore Interfaces of Superclass

Tags: gwt

I'am currently working on GWTs Activity-Place implementation. Now I have found problem with the PlaceHistoryGenerator.

I have a Tokenizer in my Place-Class. The Tokenizer is based on a Superclass. The Superclass implements the interface "PlaceTokenizer".
So far, so good! But the PlaceHistoryGenerator in GWT ignores the declared interfaces in the Superclass.

The only solution, which i have found is, to declare the interface in both (Superclass and Subclass). This makes me not really happy.

```
public abstract class BasePlaceTokenizer<P extends Place> implements PlaceTokenizer<P> {

    @Override
    public P getPlace(final String token) {
        ...
        return place;
    }

    @Override
    public String getToken(final P place) {
        ...
        return "anything...";
    }
}

public class HelloPlace {

    public static class Tokenizer extends BasePlaceTokenizer<HelloPlace> {
        // implements PlaceTokenizer<HelloPlace> {

        @Override
        public HelloPlace getPlace(final String token) {
            ...
            return place;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Thomas, the question is: Is a patch the only one solution? Thank you for the link to goolge-issue-list! I've made a comment there...

Comment: No: you can explicitly re-declare the `PlaceTokenizer` on the subclass, as you said. Or you can copy/paste (fork) the `PlaceHistoryMapperGenerator` and add the appropriate `<generate-with>` in your `gwt.xml` to override the default one.

Comment: Hello Thomas! Your second approach was already my favorite choice. ... and it works like expected ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5658

**EDIT:** fixed as of GWT 2.5.0